# spring jdbc insert command

Tags: spring, jdbc, insert, command

public void save(RegistrationBean registrationBean) throws SQLException {

```
        String first_name = registrationBean.getFirst_name();
        String last_name = registrationBean.getLast_name();
        String email = registrationBean.getEmail();
        String password = registrationBean.getPassword();
        String phone = registrationBean.getPhone();



   try {
        int rows = jdbcTemplate.update("insert into users values(?,?,?,?,?)", first_name, last_name, email,password,phone);         
        System.out.println("inserted" + rows);

    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        System.out.println(" not row inserted.reason : " + e);
    }
    }
```

this is my save method it gives sqlerror of org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [insert into users values(?,?,?,?,?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1.
Please anyone help solve the issue.

Comment: Are you sure its the above statement that's giving you error? Are you sure that your users table have 5 columns? Why don't you try `INSERT INTO users (id, name, ....) VALUES(....)`

Comment: yes i couldnt find out why it gives error.

Comment: Do you get message like not row inserted...? Did you tried my suggestion above?

Comment: yes and the reason of not insertion

Comment: what would be the syntax INSERT INTO users (id, name, ....) VALUES(....) inside values.i have 9 fields in table but other four have default value id is auto increment ,created and modified default current timestamp and status default 1.

Comment: Thank you problem solved by using your script.thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks for confirming. You could even contact me on eralmas7@yahoo.com if any further queries.